# When I try to run a script on Flask using Python 3, I do not get a server

Tags: python, flask

When I try to run a script on Flask using Python 3 (I'm trying to do the Quickstart), I do not get a server, instead I get this -

```
(base) Marcs-Air:~ marcholder$ FLASK_APP=hello.py flask run
 * Serving Flask app "hello.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: Could not import "hello"
```

Any help to fix this is much appreciated!

Comment: What do the contents of `hello.py` look like.   is there an `app` object within that?

Comment: Hi v25, it looks like this -                                                                                           from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!!!!"

Comment: That looks all correct.  You could try with `FLASK_APP=hello flask run` although it should accept `hello.py`.  Other option would be to rename that file to `app.py` and just run with `flask run` by itself.  I'd also check your flask version is up to date, as this could be a bug in a previous version maybe.

Comment: Hi vt5, I have attempted all those methods, and Flask is up to date, is there anything else I could try?

Comment: is your `.py` file in the same directory you are running the command from

Comment: It is now, thanks v25, it works!